# Golang directories organization for game server

Tags: go, architecture

I making game server in golang and i have such entities as `Player` and `Skill`. `Player` can use his skills whilst `Skill` could affect players. `Player` file and skills files live in `logic` directory(and in `package logic`). I want to move skills files into separate directory `skills`. I could not place it in logic directory and keep logic package for them cause golang not allowed it. Also i could not make `package skills` and place the directory on same level as logic directory because i got:

> import cycle not allowed

```
package main
imports projname/server/logic
imports projname/server/skills
imports projname/server/logic
```

What's wrong with my project architecture and how could i fix it?

Comment: What in the error message is unclear? You cannot have packages import each other recursively (a -> b -> c -> a).

Comment: @Volker could you suggest such project structure that handles "Player can use his skills whilst Skill could affect players."

Comment: If players and skills interact with each other it's quite obvious that they belong in the same package. If you are hell-bent on moving them to distinct packages, let one type depend on an interface instead of a concrete value from the other package. I would caution against that without good reason though.

Comment: Do what Peter suggests. Go is not Java where each class is separate.

Comment: @Peter i hell-bent to move all skills in special directory for them but not to make distinct packages. But as far as i know it is impossible make subdirectories for package in golang. So golang forces me to make the another package.

Answer (score 1):

your `main` package `imports` `logic` package. It also imports `skills` which also `imports` `logic`. Go is very strict about not allowing import cycles.

- If you are forced to `import` `logic` in `main`, because you are using some type declared in `logic` to init a function or handler in `skills`. You could, probably declare that type in `skills` rather than in `logic`.
- If you are `import`ing `logic` because some function from logic is being used in `main`. You could write a wrapper in `skills` (with a new function), which calls the function from `logic`(which is already being called).

Either way you have to try and remove the import of `logic` in `main`.